# TypeError '>' not supported between instances on Flask uploaded file

Tags: python, flask, file-upload, vuejs2, axios

it's first time that to upload a file to Flask i see this kind of error:

**TypeError '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'**

this is a webapp with VueJS and Python. VueJS use axios to make the upload

```
<template>
  <form class="ui form">
    <div class="ui action input">
        <label for="uploader"></label>
        <input
        type="file"
        name="uploader"
        id="uploader"
        ref="uploader"
        value="Choose a file"
        @change="handleFile">
        <div class="ui button" @click="Upload">Upload</div>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>
```

the axios call is

```
methods: {
  upload: function() {
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file', this.$refs.uploader.files[0])
    axios.post('test/upload', formData, {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'})
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('ok')})
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error')})
  }
}
```

and this is the Python code

```
@app.route('test/upload', methods=["POST"])
def upload():
    try:
        if request.files['file']:
            return Response(
                {"op": "ok"},
                status=200,
                mimetype="application/json")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return Response(
            {"op": "fail"},
            status=500,
            mimetype="application/json")
```

More or less those are the basics and common operations that we can find on the web, but this time it's arise the TypeError above.
With debugger mode i see this error in the output of

```
request.form
request.files
```

but not with **request.data()**.

Why i receive the error? Obviously in the browser's dev tools the request header and payload is correct.

Regards

DPope

Comment: Can you share the full traceback and perhaps more of the code please? I don't see any use of '>' in the sample of code you've posted so far so the error is probably somewhere else.

Comment: `File "/home/xxx/app/backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 196, in parse
    content_length > self.max_content_length`

Comment: `File "/home/xxx/app/backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 223, in parse
    and content_length > self.max_content_length` after the Werkzeug update to 1.6.0

Comment: SOLVED! i mistake to initialize the flask app, i've updated the MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH configuration variable with a json value but i've forgot to cast the value to int. Thanks for the good will :)